# Tag synonym(s) Nintendo Switch

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Right now we have the [nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-switch) Tag. In some questions it got edited into just [switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch). Would it be possible to add [switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch) as a synonym to the previously created tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we'll be fine sticking with [nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-switch) without the synonym - typing 'switch' into the tag field will already bring up the [nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-switch) tag and now that the [switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch) tag is uncreated, only 300+ rep users can bring it back unintentionally.

---

As for the '[switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch)' vs '[nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-switch)' discussion, again I believe we should stick with [nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-switch), because it's:

- **Unambiguous** - people misuse ambiguous tags all the time. [switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch) could be used for *anything*: switching consoles, switching camera perspective, mechanical keyboard switches, switching weapons and so on. Let's make it *perfectly clear* what this tag is for.
- **Full name**: 'Switch' as in *'the Switch'* or *'my Switch'* is colloquial. 'Nintendo Switch' is the device's full name as used by Nintendo:
- **Official**: Nintendo uses 'Nintendo Switch' in all official advertisements. Shops like EB Games/Gamestop use '[Nintendo Switch](https://ebgames.com.au/featured/nintendo-switch)'. This contrasts with consoles like *'Xbox One'*, which is known as '[Xbox One](https://ebgames.com.au/xbox-one)' and not *'Microsoft Xbox One'*

Let's not overcomplicate this by unnaturally shortening the tag because of 'convention' - a convention already broken by [nintendo-64](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-64) as Nzall has covered.

Comment: Well this answer ended up being kind of weird because the scope of the question changed from adding a synonym to deciding what the tag should be in the first place. Anyway, should it be decided to use [nintendo-switch], I think a [switch] synonym would still be helpful, just to seal the matter entirely.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - I just wanted to get my thoughts out of comment-form :-). Although I've edited my answer to better reflect the question now as well, thanks :-)

Comment: Just to add my two cents: I could see a game coming out eventually that is named "Switch", since it's a more generic word. I don't really see that happening for "Xbox", "Playstation", or "GameCube". By not making them synonyms, we can potentially prevent a little confusion that may happen in the future. (Not a fantastic reason, but thought I'd throw it out there.)

Comment: @MageXy - while it's true that could happen, synonyms can be trivially removed at any time, so even if we did add the synonym that wouldn't be a big problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think we should be consistent in how we define consoles.

[playstation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation), [xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox), [wii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wii), [windows](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), [gamecube](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamecube), [ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds), [snes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snes) and [psp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psp) are all tags that don't include the manufacturer. I don't think we should change this for the [switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch). I mean, we didn't do it for the Wii, the DS or the 3DS, which all are known with the prefix Nintendo to the general audience. The only console that's fully known with the manufacturer name is the [nintendo-64](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-64), and that makes sense. If anything, [nintendo-switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-switch) should be synonymous to [switch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch), just like the other [nintendo-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-x) tags are synonyms to [x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x)

Comment: A lot of those Nintendo console tags have [tag:nintendo-x] synonyms. Also a lot of things (even in gaming) are called "switch". In addition to that the Wikipedia article refers to the console as "Nintendo Switch" whereas this isn't the case with some other consoles like the Wii for example.

Comment: @Jutschge The Wii has been referred to as "Nintendo Wii" for a long time. Everyone's calling it the "Nintendo Switch" because it's new, but it's exactly the same as the Wii and Wii U. Its name is Switch, it should be tagged Switch.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Both "Switch" and "Nintendo Switch" are correct terms (That's why I propose a synonym not a replacement). IMO the DS tag should be Nintendo-DS by default aswell instead of just DS. The normal tag should be an official (full) name. The tag synonyms are there for commonly used abbreviations etc.

Comment: @Jutschge The official full name is Switch, Nintendo is the manufacturer.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer If you visit the [Nintendo Homepage](http://www.nintendo.com/) It's also listed as "Nintendo Switch" whereas the Wii U for example doesn't have that in it's name. Same with the 3DS. It's the "Nintendo 3DS" not just the "3DS".

Comment: @Jutschge I mentioned the Nintendo-X synonyms as well in my answer. I'm saying that we should be consistent: if all other consoles and platforms that we have tags for are without the manufacturer prefix, then the switch shouldn't have that prefix either, at least in the default tag. those other things that are also called switch are irrelevant for tags on Arqade,which are only used to indicate games and systems. As far as I can see, there are no other videogames that are named Switch.

Comment: @jutschge Beat me to it - Nintendo seems to refer to it all over their site as the Nintendo Switch so make of that what you will.

Comment: These comments are confusing.  What seems to be the consensus?

Comment: While I agree we should be consistent with defining consoles, I just think 'switch' is too generic a term to stand by itself. (Personally I would've preferred having the manufacturer on all console tags as well but that's just me).

Comment: @Robotnik What could the Switch tag be mistaken for? System transfers? We have a tag that I've seen misused many times, "Glitch", but no one has suggested to change it to "Glitch game" or anything like that.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - "*What could the Switch tag be mistaken for?*" - *Anything*, that's the problem: Mechanical keyboard switches, switching perspective in game, switching first and second player controllers, switching weapons, switching from PC to console or vice versa, it doesn't matter what's in the excerpt - users will mistag with it if it's as broad a word as 'switch' with many ambiguous meanings. People use [xbox] for Xbox 360 /One questions, [tag:minicraft] gets mistaken for Minecraft, and like you've raised, [glitch] occasionally gets used for game glitches. (cont.)

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Those are unfortunate side effects of the way those products are named - but in the case of the Nintendo Switch we have an unambiguous option (that just so happens to be the official 'branding' name from Nintendo) - and I'd rather stick to that then go with something as ambiguous as 'switch' in order to stick to a tradition that is already broken by the [nintendo-64] *anyway*.

Comment: @Robotnik Those are all valid concerns, however now I'm wondering if adding "Nintendo" to the tag would even fix those issues. If Switch were a synonym of Nintendo Switch, wouldn't it be misused in just the same way? Scratch that, even if it weren't a synonym, typing "Switch" in the tags bar would show [nintendo-switch] all the same. I've seen [games-for-windows-live] and [retro-game-challenge] misused by, I assume, hasty posters looking for any tag that would match their question, and you can't really do anything about that. Just from a usability point of view, I think the two tags would

Comment: @Robotnik work almost identically, but I agree that [nintendo-switch] might be slightly less error prone, if uglier.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - We will never stop lazy posters, nor will we stop people that just tag '[minecraft][league-of-legends][world-of-warcraft][pokemon-go][fallout-4]' in order to get their question viewed by many eyeballs - but we **will** stop people who *don't know better* - a lot of [Pokemon-Go] questions used to be tagged '[pokemon-series] [go]' because posters didn't understand that 'pokemon <space> go' in the tag box would be redirected like that. Once we synonymised [go] to [pokemon-go], the instances of [pokemon-series] being used dropped considerably.

Comment: Note that I don't think we need to synonymise [switch] in this case either - typing 'switch' in the tag box will show the nintendo-switch tag anyway